# jhipster: how to handle sql exception and show it in the angularjs front when trying to save an entity

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I would like to know how can we handle an exception related to the database when saving an entity and display it in the angularjs front end. I'm talking about exception like this :

```
DataIntegrityViolationException
```

Comment: Have you checked in JHipster code how the Zalando problem lib is used? https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web

Comment: not yet, checking it

Comment: and also have a look at `ExceptionTranslator.java`

Answer (score 1):

Add ExceptionHandler for DataIntegrityViolationException into ErrorTranslator.java as below:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleDataIntegrityViolationException(DataIntegrityViolationException ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
        Problem problem = Problem.builder()
                .withType(ErrorConstants.DATA_INTEGRITY_VIOLATION)
                .withTitle("Data integrity is violated")
                .withStatus(defaultConstraintViolationStatus())
                .with("message", ErrorConstants.ERR_VALIDATION)
                .build();
        return create(ex, problem, request);
    }
```

---

Note: `ErrorConstants.DATA_INTEGRITY_VIOLATION` and `ErrorConstants.ERR_VALIDATION` are constants declared in `ErrorConstants.java`.
You can freely define other constants if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toast to display exception. In server side, you catch exception and return to client side like this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("key-in-toast", error_message);
ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(headers).body(null);
```